How does KNNImputer stores fitted values of the train set?
If someone here is familiar with the KNNImputer implementation of Scikit-learn, I would be eager to learn this from him.
When you fit an Imputer transformer on your train data, it keeps parameters of train set in order to transform the test set accordingly (e.g SimpleImputer(method='mean') would store the mean of all feature vectors of the train set and impute test set with them).
But I can't manage to understand how KNNImputer could do this except by storing all training samples.
Thank you for your answer.

Indeed it does simply store all training samples: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/5491dc695dbe2c9bec3452be5f3c409706ff7ee7/sklearn/impute/_knn.py#L238

As I saw in the code it is more like some distance characteristics of the training samples.
